# How can I search and extract in between slash in Excel formula?

Tags: excel

I have a list of rows in excel as below.

```
Australia Order / 111233 -12213AUS / AUD900 / Ready to dispatched  
UnitedKingdom Order / 187633 -123413UK / USD 800 / goods  
1133 -1013AUS/Australia Order /  AUD450 / Ready to dispatched  
Australia Order /AUD900 / Ready to dispatched / 1873 -1726A
```

How can I search "-" and extract the value into a new column? Some of the "-' number are not in sequence after the slash.

Expected result:

```
111233 -12213AUS  
187633 -123413UK  
1133 -1013AUS  
1873 -1726A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work in your case:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1&"/",FIND("-",A1))-1),"/",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

1. Find index "/" after "-" in string -> extract text from begin to this index
2. Get last word from this string

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

There is *quite* a bit of string manipulation involved, but I guess you can try this:

```
=TRIM(MID(LEFT(A2,IFERROR(FIND("/",A2,FIND("-",A2))-1,LEN(A2))),IFERROR(FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","@",LEN(LEFT(A2,IFERROR(FIND("/",A2,FIND("-",A2))-1,LEN(A2))))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,IFERROR(FIND("/",A2,FIND("-",A2))-1,LEN(A2))),"/",""))))+1,1),LEN(A2)))
```

The formula basically locates the position of the `-` and gets the position of the previous and next `/` relative to that of the `-`.

[image]

---

Alternatively you could use text to columns and use a lookup with a wildcard:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can I understand what does this part means? "FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE...."

Comment: @user3959104 Here the goal was to find the position of the `/` that is right before `-`. To do that, I'm taking the text up to right before the first `/` after `-`, in that text, I substitute the last `/` (which becomes the one before `-`) by `@`. When the replacement is done, I can find the position of `@`. For example, `Australia Order /AUD900 / Ready to dispatched / 1873 -1726A` would become `Australia Order /AUD900 / Ready to dispatched @ 1873 -1726A`, thus I can now easily find the position of the only `@` in the text. Note: this works only if there's no other `@` already in there.